# Can I run any lower than my current version of macOS through a virtualisation or emulation environment like Parallels?

Tags: virtualization, parallels-desktop, vmware, apple-silicon, intel

My goal is to have access to the install of my old Mac on my new Mac without operating two Macs side-by-side. The configurations are:

- Old Mac:

  - El Capitan 10.11.6
  - Intel processor
- New Mac

  - Ventura 13.0
  - Apple M1 processor

The reason is that I will need some applications from the old Mac for which I don't have equivalents on the new Mac.

Is there a possibility to run these older apps on the new Mac in virtualised or emulated environment on the new Mac like Parallels, VMWare or another app?

Comment: Which applications are you referring to? I ask because Macs with M1 processors can use Rosetta 2 to run 64 bit Intel based applications.

Comment: I have a 2010 version of Microsoft Office that I find more than sufficient for my needs. So I'd rather not have to buy a new one. I'm currently experimenting with LibreOffice, but ideally I'd like to use my old MS Office copy. I also have an older Adobe CS6 version that I'd like to run. The icons show up with an overlayed circle and strikethrough. Opening one of these apps, I get the message "XYZ needs to be updated".

Comment: I have 2011 version of Microsoft Office, Adobe CS5 and CS6 applications. I am currently trying to get these to run on a [refurbished 2018 Intel Mac mini](https://www.apple.com/shop/refurbished/mac/mac-mini) with Ventura. Using Parallels to run these applications in older versions of OS X and macOS seems to work so far. I do not think this is possible with a M1 Mac. From reading the answers and comments posted so far, I think you will not be able to run your older applications with any reasonable performance on your new M1 Mac.

Comment: After some investigation, I see Photoshop CS6 is a 64 bit application. So I tried installing in macOS Catalina, which supports 64 bit applications, but not 32 bit applications. I discovered, the installer for Photoshop CS6 will not execute, because the installer is 32 bit.

Comment: @DavidAnderson So if the app itself is 64 bit (and therefore should run on the new machine) shouldn't it be possible to transfer the executables (app folder) and preferences over? — I just had a look at my system (via System Information > Software > Applications) and my incarnation of Photoshop CS6 v13.0.6 and is 64 bit, so is Illustrator CS6, but strangely not InDesign CS6.

Comment: Those 64 bit apps are obviously Intel 64 bit and I therefore wonder if that's the reason it can't be executed, even in Rosetta2.

Comment: I used the Migration Assistant to transfer all my applications from a Mac with High Sierra to a Parallels VM running Mojave on a different Mac. Both High Sierra and Mojave can run 32 bit apps. After installing the required legacy Java, the CS5 apps could be started, but quick closed. Adobe Acrobat Reader DC runs, but first required me to accept the license. The point is that Adobe software has the ability to know when ported to a different Mac. Both CS5 and CS6 require a key to install the software.

Comment: I think the Adobe software requiring a key is smart enough to not start when moved to a new machine. Adobe Acrobat Reader DC is free and does not require a key to install. Therefore, Adobe Acrobat Reader DC will start and run when ported to a new machine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140426/discussion-between-david-anderson-and-alex-ixeras).

Comment: There are several issues here: 32 bit apps can not run on anything newer than 10.14. Rosetta can run any Intel app that is compiled with support for the os you are running (2011 binaries will not have). The binary can be universal (Xcode 12.2) but that was new for Big Sur.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a possibility to run these older apps on the new Mac in a virtual environment on the new Mac like Parallels, VMWare or another app?

Yes! The [best solution for older macOS is UTM](https://mac.getutm.app/), which is actually just QEMU. I’ve used QEMU for old Intel virtual machines (via emulation), despite it is very **slow**. I'll try to impress on you how slow; imagine taking your El Capitan 10.11.6 virtual machine and run it on an original Intel Pentium from 1993. That is the level of performance you will experience.

A comparison of technologies:

| Feature | QEMU | Fusion | Parallels |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Type | Emulation & Virtualization | Virtualization | Virtualization |
| Speed | Emulation (slow) Virtualization (fast) | Fast | Fast |
| Limitations | [Configuration is not trivial](https://khronokernel.github.io/apple/silicon/2021/01/17/QEMU-AS.html) | Tech Preview does not support macOS yet | Oldest supported is Monterey |
| Intel CPU support | Via Emulation | None, likely never | None, likely never |

**Virtualization** is emulation of hardware, such as Ethernet, Bluetooth, Disk controllers, and boot environments (EFI). The operating system has to be the same CPU architecture.
**Emulation** is virtualization of the CPU, which is required to run an Intel operating system on an ARM system like the Apple M1/M2. Virtualization of hardware may also be required.

The technology in QEMU to emulate began in 2009, the only other similar project is Bochs. QEMU is clearly the better performing of the two.

For an example of exactly how slow, in [this article they ran Geekbench](https://khronokernel.github.io/apple/silicon/2021/01/17/QEMU-AS.html) inside an Intel emulated system. The emulated Intel scored **68**, but a native M1 scored **1730**. That is a loss of 96% of the speed of native.

Comment: For the sake of the original question, which was about the practicality of using applications that only run on El Capitan and not Monterey/Ventura, I think it is important for this answer that it is not really a practical answer. If you expect to be able to fire up UTM/qemu and just run "that old Word Processor" (or whatever it might) to edit "that old document".... it's not really that smooth. You should be prepared to wait 10 minutes just to start up the system, and then additional minutes for launching "that old program"... everything is just insanely slow compared to even an old Mac.

Comment: @jksoegaard good point, I copied the question in as a quote and made a point of expanding on just how painfully slow this will be.

Comment: Thanks @JamesRisner. I didn't consider the differences between a virtualisation and an emulation. Obviously, I'm facing the issue of emulation here, which makes me cringe. How is it that some of my El Capitan apps can run on Ventura, but others don't?

Comment: Xcode allows you to set a minimum (in that case 10.11) OS supported. Xcode 14.1 for example can make applications run on 10.13+. I believe some of the Xcode 13.x releases supported 10.11 OS. So some apps were compiled that way. It's implemented by adding extra code to handle the different ways to do some non-portable things for each OS.

Comment: @AlexIxeras Another point that might not be obvious, the last several Xcode versions produce 64 bit code for both Intel and ARM. So it works on any supported macOS.

Comment: @JamesRisner So I had a look at the UTM site and they promise "UTM employs Apple's Hypervisor virtualization framework to run ARM64 operating systems on Apple Silicon at near native speeds." If it's as slow as you say, is "near native speeds" a euphemism?

Comment: You need an Intel version of the OS to run an 10.11 to 10.15 application. Download St Clair’s “Go64.app”. If it says the application is Universals and 64 then you could hypervisor it. I’m guessing it will say 32bit and Intel, if so Emulation.

Comment: For MS Office, you need the 2016 or 2019 version. I use the Office 2016 and Libreoffice on my M1. I highly doubt you will be able to get the CS6 working as it is very unlikely to support changes made in newer macOS (even if 64 bit Intel Rosetta can translate but the OS calls will still be incompatible)

Comment: Thanks. I've run Go64 and it tells me that CS6 is 64-bit except for some apps contained within, e.g. for Photoshop there are 2 32-bit apps in the container. My 2011 Office is definitely 32-bit. That's why I wanted to give UTM a try. When I select "Create a New Virtual Machine" > Emulate > Other and point to the OS X 10.11 DMG I downloaded from Apple, I'm asked about a System configuration on the "Hardware" screen, but they only seem to offer PCs, no Macs.

Comment: @AlexIxeras what you are trying is uncommon and I highly doubt UTM test anything before Monterey. It is just uncommon to create old macOS VMs. Here is a VMWare work thru for El Capitan: https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Fusion-Discussions/Trying-to-create-a-old-OS-X-virtual-machine-but-can-t-get-it-run/m-p/1873791#M111887

Comment: @JamesRisner Thanks. I think this won't work for me because of the different CPU architectures. If my new Mac would be an Intel CPU this solution could've worked, I suppose.

Comment: It’s still applicable, you’d just need to swap VMWare for UTM. **1)** Install Monterey in UTM, **2)** Add a second disk, **3)** Download El Capitain in the VM and run to get the installer. **4)** Install on the second disk. **5)** Move the second disk to a new VM.

Comment: @JamesRisner I found links to the IPSWs on ipsw.me. Do I see it right that I need to stop the VM created in step 1, then edit this VM and add a new drive to it for step 2? Upon restarting the VM, it recognised there is a new disk that hasn't been initialised. I did that as a Mac OS Extended (HFS+). I then went to support.apple.com/en-us/HT211683 to download El Capitan, but when I started El Capitan (from within the Monterey VM), I got the error message "This version of OS X 10.11 cannot be installed on this computer." I found an "Install OS X El Capitan" app, which I also tried: same result.

Comment: @AlexIxeras do you had a working Monterey in a UTM VM? Reboot, added a drive. Opening the DMG gave that error? You may wish to try the next newer OS

Comment: Just to clarify, you know this will be 4% of the speed of a native app? I’m not sure you could use this in production without being very frustrated?

Comment: @JamesRisner Hope you don't mind, if we continue here (https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140604/creating-a-lower-macos-in-a-virtualised-environment), so that I can attach some screenshots. And yes, I'm aware that the system might be slower. I wonder whether it'll be really 4% but in most cases I won't be doing extraneous work there.

Comment: I tried downloading the next newer OS (Big Sur), but my newer Mac doesn't allow me to download this version (because it's not compatible with it). I've also tried this macOS 11.2.3 Developer Transition Kit (from https://ipsw.me/download/ADP3,2/20D91), but pointing UTM to this only results in the UEFI Interactive Shell, of which I posted a screenshot in the chat at the link above (i.e. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140604/creating-a-lower-macos-in-a-virtualised-environment).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the difference in CPU architecture. Virtualization works because the software is just pretending to be another OS running on the same sort of CPU as it would do natively.

When you 'mix' CPU types, then the VM has to translate the Intel code into ARM instructions in real time, instead of just passing it on to the CPU. This is usually called "emulation", not "virtualization".

Apple already provides Rosetta, which creates a translated version of an application's code: but doing the translation at the OS level is much more difficult (because most of what an OS does is about controlling hardware) and involves a large performance penalty for the extra work.

In short: your goal of having a virtual copy of your old Mac on your new one is not practicable.

Either keep your old Mac and use Screen Sharing or Universal Control to access it from your new Mac; or just migrate all your files and use new versions of your apps.

Answer (score 1):

[According to Parallels](https://www.parallels.com/eu/products/desktop/resources/#requirements) - you can run an older version of MacOS as a Guest Operating System, but there are limitations. In short, you can only run the ARM version of MacOS 12 or 13 on your M1 Mac.

Regarding VMWare - it looks like the latest version that runs on M1 Macs is currently a tech preview, version 22H2. According to VMWare's [release notes](https://blogs.vmware.com/teamfusion/2022/07/just-released-vmware-fusion-22h2-tech-preview.html):

- Fusion will not support running VMs across different architectures.
  (I.e. no x86_64 VMs on M1 Macs).
- macOS virtual machines are out of scope for this release, but it’s something we’re looking into.

So, currently, neither of these applications will support running El Capitan in a virtualized manner on your M1 Mac under Ventura. Perhaps you can investigate if the applications you need will run on 10.12 on an M1 machine under Rosetta 2. Check [here](https://eclecticlight.co/2022/06/11/explainer-virtualisation-and-rosetta-2/) for some background on this.